# ASP.Net OWIN Setting Cookie but User is Immediately Logged Out

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net

I have been having this problem for a couple months. The issue is sporadic and difficult to reproduce, but I have managed to find a somewhat consistent way to do it. I am debugging and see that as soon as it should redirect to /home/index, it goes to /account/logoff instead. If I test locally then it will work on the first login fine then it will fail if I use a different account. I set the CookieName and CookieSecure after seeing a couple of posts related to them. It didn't seem to help though.

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
            CookieName = "NewImprovedCookieName",
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOff"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity =
                        SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
        });
```

The LogOff happens right after this last line of code here.

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I tried updating everything in the project to see if it was a bug that was fixed at some point (this was an old project), but nothing seemed to help it.

Is there a way to fix this, or should I consider migrating to .Net Core?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but I did find one that works.  I noticed that the SessionID was persisting after logging out.  I added code to remove abandon the session and change the session ID, and it appears to be working now.

```
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```